# I want to make my program tell the user that there input is invalid for a multiple choice question

Tags: python

I have a multiple choice question but I want the code to tell the user that there input is wrong if they have inputted an invalid answer:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCtz8.png

Ive used a != statement which has only worked for single answer questions:

if drinkselect != "cola":

print("Not on our menu!\n")

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: just add else: modifier and print("invalid option") at the bottom

Comment: @cesebe27 It comes up with invalid option on every answer including the right ones

Comment: `while True: deliverySelect = input if(deliverySelect== "yes): ... elif(deliverySelect == "no"): ... else: print("invalid option")`

Comment: @cesebe27 I used that code and it still does the same thing: Do you want delivery? 
 Yes: Delivery 
 No: No Delivery 
 
 (no)
invalid option

Comment: you should have made something  wrong, let me see the code

Comment: @cesebe27 sorry for late reply, it does work but when i do this it keeps asking the question over and over, so it basically cant go into the next question.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Instead, please [edit] your question to include your code as [formatted text](/editing-help#syntax-highlighting).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
while True:
    deliveryselect=input('Do you want delivery? \n Yes: Delivery\n No: No delivery \n \n')
    if deliveryselect=='Yes'or deliveryselect=='yes':
        print('Thank You')
        break
    elif deliveryselect =='No' or deliveryselect=='no':
        print('Thank you')
        break
    else:
        print('Invalid Choice')
```

Answer (score 1):

```py
while True:   
    delivery=input("input......")
    if delivery == "yes":
        print("yes....")
         
    elif delivery == "no":
        print("no...")
         
    else:
        print("invalid input....")
```

Comment: When i do this it works but it keeps asking the question over and over, so it basically cant go into the next question.

Comment: I think  then  while True is not needed(just remove the first line)

Comment: I get an error message without it

Comment: IndentationError?

Comment: Yes thats the error

Comment: That is due to tab space error